# PHP Using DOM to output XLS

Tags: php, xml, dom, xls

I'm trying to output an XLS file in the XML format.

This is what the data should look like for Excel 2003 to render (can be saved as an xls file):

```
<? xml version='1.0' ?>
<? mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet' ?>
<Workbook xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel' xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet' xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
    <Worksheet ss:Name='Connections'>
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><B>Test</B></Data></Cell>
                <Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><B>Test 2</B></Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>Data</Data></Cell>
                <Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>More data</Data></Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

What I'm currently getting is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Test">
        <Table>
            <Row>
                <Cell><ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="string"><B>Test</B></ss:Data></Cell>
                <Cell><ss:Data xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" ss:Type="string"><B>Test 2</B></ss:Data></Cell>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Cell><ss:data ss:type="string">Data</ss:Data></Cell>
                <Cell><ss:data ss:type="string">More data</ss:Data></Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Which Excel can't parse. It throws four of these errors in its log file:

```
XML ERROR in Table
REASON: Bad Value
FILE:   test.xls
GROUP:  Cell
TAG:    Data
ATTRIB: Type
VALUE:  string
```

I think that the main problem is that the `<ss:Data>` tags which I'm creating with `DomDocument::CreateElement('ss:Data')` should be closed with `</Data>`, whereas DomDocument is outputting `</ss:Data>`. I can't use `CreateElementNS()`, because there isn't a namespace (I think — I'm not really familiar with XML past the basics) and using `CreateElementNS('','ss:Data')` causes the script to die with absolutely no errors with XDebug installed and error_reporting set to `E_ALL & E_STRICT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ss:Type='String'
```

not

```
ss:Type='string'
```

the type is case-sensitive

Comment: Complex question, simple answer. Great!